# Multiple values in square bracket csv in R

Tags: r, csv, square-bracket, multiple-value

I have a csv file like this:

```
1556891503.326399;16384;340;48188.23529411765;[1618.377685546875, 1620.2911376953125, 1620.1904296874998, 1619.9386596679685, 1620.391845703125, 1620.2911376953125, 1620.794677734375, 1618.1762695312498, 1620.8450317382812, 1621.0968017578125, 1620.3414916992188, 1620.7443237304685, 1620.391845703125, 1620.9457397460935,...]; 155689433.326399;16384;340;48188.23529411765;[1618.377685546875, 1620.2993876953125, 1620.1904296874998, 1619.9386596679685, 1620.391845703125, 1620.2911376953125..];...
```

There are 5 features and the last one is a huge sensor data in one cell in square brackets and separated with commas. I would like to take mean, mode, sd.. etc. of this sensor data but I don't know how to remove it from brackets and analyze it. I try the modify it as String but the data is huge and the processing time is long! 
Is there any easier way?

Comment: Can you read the data into R and post `dput(head(data))` here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not the best or prettiest way, but the below method will work.

It is not clear how your file is formatted, but because you said "There are 5 features and the last one is", I assume your data looks like this:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1556891503,155689433),V2=c(16384,16384),V3=c(340,340),V4=c(12,12),V5=c("[12,12,12,23]","[8,8,8,8]"))

           V1    V2  V3 V4            V5
 1 1556891503 16384 340 12 [12,12,12,23]
 2  155689433 16384 340 12     [8,8,8,8]
```

You can read that csv using `read.csv` and `sep=";"`

```
df <- read.csv("myFile.csv",sep= ";", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$V5 <- gsub("\\[","",df$V5)
df$V5 <- gsub("\\]","",df$V5)
```

You can then `split` the 5th column using `strsplit(df$V5,split = ", ")`, convert it to numeric

```
df$V6 <- strsplit(df$V5,split = ", ")
df$V6 <- sapply(df$V6, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))
```

and calculate your statistics

```
df$mean <- sapply(df$V6, function(x) mean(unlist(x)))
df$sd <- sapply(df$V6, function(x) sd(unlist(x)))

     mean        sd
1 1620.201 0.8779917
2 1619.915 0.7689437
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The file is exactly like you created. I tried your code but I got an error in this part:
dataPump$V6 <- sapply(dataPump$V5, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, V6, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 16384 rows, data has 882

Comment: there was a typo, try with `sapply(dataPump$V6`. The `strsplit`ed column is now `V6`, not `V5`.

Comment: I already fixed that typo. The error source is something different I guess. 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, V6, value = c(1618.37768554688, 1620.29113769531,  : 
  replacement has 16384 rows, data has 882

Comment: You should then post your data, because using the line in your question, the code works .

Comment: They closed the topic so I cant post anymore but I modify it and this works:
dataPump$V6 <- strsplit(dataPump$V5, split = ",")
dataPump$V6 <- lapply(dataPump$V6, as.numeric, options(digits=12))
Thank you very much!